# Record is not added in to the database using java mysql

Tags: java

i am trying to add the data into the database but the record is not added in 
 to the database .everything working fine database connection and query. I don't know why I attach the code below

```
public void makeConnection()
 {

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
    Connection con1; con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javasales","root","");         
        String query = " insert into sales_product (product, price)"
        + " values (?, ?)";

      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) con1.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setString (1, txtproduct.getText());
      preparedStmt.setString (2, txtprice.getText());


      // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException coe)
      {
        System.out.println("odbc driver not found");
         }
        catch(SQLException sqe)
      {
        System.out.println(sqe);
      }

 }
```

[image]

Comment: @user43648 The punctuation in your comment is incorrect.

Comment: where do `txtproduct` and `txtprice` come from? Does it work if you replace those with test strings? eg `"testProduct" and "testPrice"`

Comment: if "working fine database connection and query" is the case, then a new record will show up in `sales_product `. Debug your application please.

Comment: yes it will shown up in the database sales_product table blanck    only autoincrement id will be incremented when i add the new record

Comment: i attached the image above  how my record is shown on the table after the add the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have auto-commit setted on your db,

you should add `Connection.commit()` to commit your changes